# Coordinate Reference System change problem in GeoTools

Tags: coordinate-system, geotools

I try to convert some coordinates from ETRS89-LAEA (EPSG:3035) to WGS84 (EPSG:4326) with geotools. Here is the code:

```
Coordinate c = new Coordinate(3847988.7, 3161178.2);
MathTransform mt = CRS.findMathTransform(
   CRS.decode("EPSG:3035"),
   CRS.decode("EPSG:4326"));
c = JTS.transform(new GeometryFactory().createPoint(c), mt).getCoordinate();
System.out.println(c);
```

As a final result, I get:

```
(56.34206943661075, -8.998327460134755)
```

which is obviously wrong. What is wrong with my code?

**Note:**

```
    System.out.println(CRS.decode("EPSG:3035"));
```

returns:

```
PROJCS["ETRS89 / LAEA Europe", 
  GEOGCS["ETRS89", 
    DATUM["European Terrestrial Reference System 1989", 
      SPHEROID["GRS 1980", 6378137.0, 298.257222101, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]], 
      TOWGS84[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","6258"]], 
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
    AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
    AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4258"]], 
  PROJECTION["Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area", AUTHORITY["EPSG","9820"]], 
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_center", 52.0], 
  PARAMETER["longitude_of_center", 10.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 4321000.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 3210000.0], 
  UNIT["m", 1.0], 
  AXIS["Northing", NORTH], 
  AXIS["Easting", EAST], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","3035"]]
```

and

```
    System.out.println(CRS.decode("EPSG:4326"));
```

returns:

```
GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
  DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
    SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
  PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
  UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
  AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
  AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
```

which both seem correct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK: It is a matter of swapping X <-> Y coordinates in the input...

A possible fix is:

```
CRS.decode("EPSG:3035", true);
CRS.decode("EPSG:4326", true);
```

or (as suggested by Ian Turton below), to simply change the order in the coordinates:

```
Coordinate c = new Coordinate(3161178.2, 3847988.7);
```

Comment: The clue is in the definition both are North East projections so yx, so the better fix is to fix the order in your coordinates